# Error al ordenar alfanuméricamente con javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código javascript:

```
var asientos = ["C11", "C10"];
asientos.sort();
console.log(asientos);
```

En este caso si ordena bien es decir: ["C10", "C11"]

El problema viene cuando ahora pongo un valor menor a 10 por ejemplo:

```
var asientos = ["C11", "C9"];
```

En este caso no ordena bien, lo deja así: ["C11", "C9"]

Por que esta teniendo ese comportamiento, ojala que pudieran ayudarme.

Comment: Es similar pero acá no es solamente numérico (aunque se tenga signos negativos), ya que también involucra letras del alfabeto, abajo coloqué la respuesta que encontré dentro de la comunidad también, pero en inglés

saludos

Comment: el ordenamiento para ser string ,esta bien si quieres hacer un orden numerico debes ordenar numeros no letras  cambia tu array de la siguiente forma` [{"C" : [11, 9]}]` o reescribe la funcion sort como dice Trauma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta la encontré en el sitio en inglés:

```
var reA = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
var reN = /[^0-9]/g;

function sortAlphaNum(a, b) {
  var aA = a.replace(reA, "");
  var bA = b.replace(reA, "");
  if (aA === bA) {
    var aN = parseInt(a.replace(reN, ""), 10);
    var bN = parseInt(b.replace(reN, ""), 10);
    return aN === bN ? 0 : aN > bN ? 1 : -1;
  } else {
    return aA > bA ? 1 : -1;
  }
}
console.log(
["A1", "A10", "A11", "A12", "A2", "A3", "A4", "B10", "B2", "F1", "F12", "F3"].sort(sortAlphaNum)
)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340227/sort-mixed-alpha-numeric-array

Saludos compañero

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero, me salvaste la vida

Comment: Para eso estamos, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Fijate en los dos primeros caracteres del string, "C9" es *mayor* que "C1", para que te lo ordene correctamente deberias poner:

`var asientos = ["C11", "C09"];`